# UWP TextBox method for undo command

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, uwp, undo

I know that textbox has command for undo by default, when I press ctrl+Z. I'm creating UWP application and I need to call this command by pressing some button in GUI. How can I do it? Is there some method like textbox.Undo()?

Comment: There's an API in UWP for creating fake input data. Unfortunately cannot remember its name but using it you should be able to simulate the CTRL+Z keypress.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find anything like Textbox.Undo(), but you could save all changes in a list and revert the text when needed.

.XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}" />
```

.CS:

```
private List<string> _history;

private double _myText;
public double MyText
{
    get { return _myText; }
    set
    {
        if(_myText != value) {
            _myText = value;
            _history.Add(value);
            //Notify
        }
    }
}

private void Undo() {
    _myText = _history.LastOrDefault();
    //Notify
}
```

Comment: I know this is the way, how to solve it. But I want to call the default undo command. I hope there should be some way, how to call it, otherwise it is useless, when we can't call it whenever we want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ApplicationCommand Class.
Just set ApplicationCommand.Undo in button command you want to get click and perform undo operation..and set Target type= the name of the textbook.

```
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" Width="75" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"/>

  <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="25"
           TextWrapping="Wrap">  
  </TextBox>
```

[This is a link for ApplicationCommand Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.undo(v=vs.100).aspx)

[ApplicationCommands Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This solution is not applicable for UWP